# "Later on" vs "More later"

Tags: future-time

Is there any difference using the expression "Later on" vs "More later"? for example:

I will work later on

and

I will work more later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't be compared since the locution *more later*, strictly speaking, is not grammatical. The adverb *more* is used to form comparative forms of adjectives and adverbs that are more than one syllable long. Comparative forms of adjectives and adverbs that are made up of only one syllable are formed differently. We use the *er* ending to show that an adjective or an adverb is in its comparative form. The adverb *later* is already in its comparative form as indicated by the er at the of it. So, *more later*, grammatically speaking, makes no sense. You should only use *later*:

> I will work on it **later**.
>
> **Later on** that day, I went to the store and bought me a can of sardines.

Comment: Agreed, though you'd be understood by a native, using the OP's 2nd version, if the context was along the lines of "I only did a small amount of work now, I will do more later" where 'more' refers to the quantity of work rather than the quantity of lateness.

Comment: That's a good point. But the context in your example is, of course, completely different from the one used in the OP's example.

Comment: Indeed. I was just pointing out that with the right context it is *technically possible* & may have been cause for the OP's confusion, having seen it used in that way by a native. The 2 examples are not analogous to one another, of course.